# Change the display property on a dynamic iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am creating an iFrame dynamically on many pages. The iFrame contains a dialog where the user enters some information. This is on a separate webserver because several websites need to use this same dialog. When the user is finished entering data, it hides the dialog by just changing the display of the divs to none. The only problem is that the iFrame is still there, it is transparent but any content under the iFrame cannot be clicked. Is there anyway when the dialog inside the iFrame performs a specified action that it would change the iFrame to display to none on the page that the iFrame lives on?

```
var PageOutput = "<iframe id=\"FiFrame\" src=\"myPage-1.html\" style=\"display: none; border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 500px; width: 300px; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;\"></iframe>";
var Icon = "<a href=\"#\" id=\"FLink\"><img src=\"images/feedback_button.png\" alt=\"\" style=\"position: fixed; right: 40%; top: 20%;\"/></a>";
$(document).ready(function() {
$(PageOutput).appendTo( document.body );
$(Icon).appendTo( document.body );
$('#FLink').click(function() {
    $('#FiFrame').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some cross site bodging to make a call to the original page.

- Page 1. Top page (site - example1.com) loads...
- Page 2. iframe (site - example2.com). On completion loads...
- Page 3. iframe with javscript (site - example1.com).

Page 3 would need to be a page that includes a script to call to the top window on load (window.top.hideIframe().. or something)

Also Page 2 would need to know the original calling site so as to be able to call the correct site when calling Page 3.

Sorry if this makes no sense.